# How can give url parameters to proxy_pass with nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx

i have a node front end server working on `localhost:3000` and express server working on `localhost:5000`

and in `/` location my config is

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #whatever port your app runs on
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

when I send a request to `localhost:5000` i get `(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error and I think Nginx is blocking me to do requests

so I want to give a `/api` location that will take the URL parameters after the `/api/` and put it in front of `localhost:5000`

for example:
when I go to `domain.com/api/admin/news` the request will be sent to `localhost:5000/api/admin/news`

I'm trying to fo this with this config but I can't get it to work

```
location /~* ^/api/(.*){
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/$1$is_args$args; 
}
```

any help will be very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: You could use: `location /api/ { ... proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/; }`

Comment: Is your location rule correct?

`location ~^/api/(.*){`
seems to be working

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you very very much, Richard, have a beautiful day 

Comment: @PavelDubenko the thing that Richard suggested worked, thank  you for answering anyway